# How to acces admin button in github?

Tags: github

I am trying to go through instructions to upload my Django site to a hosting. There is an "Admin" button mentioned. According to the screen shot it should be situated on the left of "Unwatch" button. But I do not have it. How to make it visible?

[image: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-K9_vCPoL3fo/TlUzwk0UNDI/AAAAAAAAAX8/R5ufaxQ4CH0/s1600/github_step2.png]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an old screenshot of GitHub.

It should now be the "settings": [github.com/elektrik/django-hello-world](https://github.com/elektrik/django-hello-world/settings), in the right part of the page.

The "Post-Receive URL" service hook os now part of the **[webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)**, which includes a [push event](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events).

Comment: Sorry to annoy with my old manual but "Post-Receive URL" service hook looks like to be outdated (renamed?). Could you suggest a replacement for that?
http://blog.getbarista.com/2011/08/how-to-deploy-public-github-project-on.html